# Is there a standard way to hyphenate a mathmode symbol with a word?

Tags: math-mode, hyphenation

Is there a "standard" or "best practice" way to hyphenate a mathematical symbol with a word?

Examples: `$\delta$-interleaved`, `$k$-dimensional`, `$1-$critical`, etc.

Should the hyphen go inside or outside the math mode?

Comment: If the hyphen goes in math mode it will be a minus sign.

Comment: outside, it's  hyphen not  minus sign

Comment: *facepalm* thanks !

Comment: Better still, load the `amsmath` package and write `$\delta$\nobreakdash-interleaved`, `$k$\nobreakdash-dimensional`, and `$1$\nobreakdash-critical`. That way, the words will *never* get hyphenated at the first character that follows `\nobreakdash` (here: `-` in all three cases), but TeX will still allow hyphenation to occur later on in the compound words, e.g., `inter-leaved`, `di-men-sional`, and `crit-i-cal`.